# Speed of growth of Spock's hair on Genesis

Tags: star-trek, spock

When Spock was being rapidly regenerated on the Genesis Planet in *Star Trek III: The Search For Spock*, why didn't his hair and beard grow rapidly as well since he was rapidly being regenerated? Is this a movie plot hole or am I missing something?

Comment: this leads me to another question, to vulcans have facial hair?

Comment: Not every continuity or production error is a "plot hole".

Comment: Mirror Universe Spock had an epic goatee.

Comment: Exactly, it's an oversight, not a plot hole.

Comment: @Himarm doesn't Tuvok grow a moustache at some stage in Voyager? I'm pretty sure I remember him with a moustache.

Comment: @Daft - http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/3/38/Tulak.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080530211024&path-prefix=en

Comment: @Richard haha! I knew it!

Comment: “why didn't his hair and beard grow rapidly as well since he was rapidly being regenerated?” — is that what happens when things are rapidly regenerated in real life then?

Comment: @Himarm Yes, Vulcans grow facial hair. Tuvok was seen shaving on Voyager (Year of Hell-he cut himself due to being blind) and Sybok had a Sean Conneryesque beard in Star Trek V.

Answer (score 4):

One plausible explanation - and this is largely speculation - is that the Genesis process wasn't simply rebuilding Spock's body from purely DNA, but was somehow using his corpse as the template. **Given that we know so little about how the Genesis device works, and especially how it interacted with Spock, it's entirely possible that it was restoring Spock to a previous condition - kind of like a backup copy.**

What little evidence I have to support this is found within "Star Trek III: The Search for Spock" itself. Since Spock was found as a child, many fans have assumed that the Genesis process was rebuilding Spock from his Vulcan DNA. Although this would explain why he went through the aging & growth process again, it does NOT explain what happened to his original body. If Genesis were simply building him a new body (which would have hair growth as you stated), then his original body would still be inside the torpedo casing found by Dr. Marcus & Saavik. Instead, the corpse was gone and the microbes on the outside of the casing had rapidly evolved into new life-forms.

Based on the fact that it appears to be Spock's original body "reset" to a period of childhood, I believe that the Genesis effect was actually restoring him to his previous state - as he was right before death. If this is true, and granted that's a big IF, it would explain why his hair returned to a length and state similar to before. It would also explain why he rapidly aged to his previous appearance, then began aging normally again.

Comment: yeah the fact that he aged to a fully grown adult, to me means that it was bringing him back to his actual age at  death, because otherwise it was completely arbitrary where his ageing would end. ive read articles on how human dna/rna can only replicate so many times before it breaks down and that outer limit determines how long 1 would live in perfect condition, which would mean the DNA/RNA of Spock, would have already experienced some decay, so the genesis process would be able to age him to that decay point. But would not go past, or stop sooner.